# Electron Forge + Angular 4 breaks with `'anonymous' is not a known element`

Tags: angular, electron, electron-forge

I've got a fresh install of Electron Forge with the `angular2` template. I bumped the Angular dependencies to `^4.3.1`, `zone.js` to `^0.8.14` and added `hammerjs` to `package.json` (to use Angular 4 material components).

I then added the source of a functional NG4 app in the `src/app` directory.

When running `electron-forge start` the console output is correct and the app starts, but the DevTools show this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'anonymous' is not a known element:
1. If 'anonymous' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("tin\Desktop\ef-ng\node_modules\electron-compile\lib\protocol-hook.js:216:25)
    at Generator.next ([ERROR ->]<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\Quentin\Desktop\ef-ng\node_modules\electron-compile\lib\protocol-h"): ng:///C:/Users/Quentin/Desktop/ef-ng/src/app/app.component.html@4:23
```

Here's how my `app.component.html` looks:

```
<app-main-toolbar></app-main-toolbar>
<app-tree-item-tabs></app-tree-item-tabs>
<app-search-view *ngIf="appState.searchIsVisible"></app-search-view>
<app-media-view *ngIf="appState.activeMedia" [media]="appState.activeMedia"></app-media-view>
```

If I replace it with this, then it runs OK (but of course this is not what I'm looking for):

```
<app-main-toolbar></app-main-toolbar>
<app-tree-item-tabs></app-tree-item-tabs>
<app-search-view></app-search-view>
```

Notice I removed the `app-media-view` component and the `*ngIf` on the `app-search-view` one. I used to use a trick adding `moduleId : module.id.split('\\').join('/'),` to my `@Component` declarations, but that doesn't work here.

I'm really stuck here.

Any idea?
Thanks!

## Edit

Here's how `media` is defined in `app-media-view` :

```
get media(): Media {
    return this._media;
}

@Input()
set media(value: Media) {
    this._media = value;
    // More things
}
```

Here's how `appState`  is defined in the `AppComponent` :

```
constructor(
    protected bootstrap:BootstrapService,
    public appState: AppStateService) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is some bad reference in your components app-search-view or app-media-view.

Do you have declared `@Input() media: any;` in your `app-media-view` component?

Does `appState` declared in your app-component? Maybe you could try to print them and see.

If you added source of a functional NG4 app (not electron-forge) in the src/app directory, you need to change all the imports and references to the template and styles.
`app` is not your root folder anymore. Now the root folder is `src`. So for instance if you have `templateUrl: ./myTemplate.html` you have to change to `templateUrl: ./src/app/myTemplate.html`.

Comment: Just answered your questions in a recent edit, I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

add "moduleId : module.id.split('\').join('/'), " in your component definition would do the trick:

```
@Component({
  moduleId : module.id.split('\\').join('/'), 
  selector: 'App',
  templateUrl:'./app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {//...}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned in my question, this trick used to work but doesn't anymore :(